# gstreamer-1.0 get data from GstSample in GstAppSink

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to get data from a GstSample to process it in my app sink.
But I cannot find a way to extract the data from a sample.
I have set the callball function "new-sample":

```
static void GStPipeline::new_sample (GstAppSink *sink, CustomData *data) {
    GstSample* sample;

    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(data->app_sink);

    if (sample) {
        data->sampleBuffer[data->num_samples] =  sample;

        data->num_samples++;
    }

    gst_sample_unref(sample);
}
```

Am I missing some basic concept? Is it true, that since gstreamer-1.0 I have to provide a callback "new-sample" instead of "pull-buffer" ? For my understanding, a buffer contains the samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you kind of got it right. The GstAppSink is pretty well documented about the callbacks. You just have to go a little further to access the data.

`sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(sink)
  buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample)
    gst_buffer_map(buffer, &info, GST_MAP_READ)`

Where `info` is of type `GstMapInfo`. Your data is then found at

`info.data` with a payload length of `info.size`.

Comment: The use of the terminology samples is somewhat different then I expected. A sample is contained in a buffer. A buffer contains the actual audio data, which for my usual understanding is called samples...

Comment: I can be confusing but think this way: In GStreamer a sample/buffer can contain any kind of data - raw, encoded or muxed.. audio or video. So their used terms probably will never make any assumption on the contents. So "audio samples" or "video frames" is on another layer - after you isolated your data/payload.